# QField: get the altitude into an attribute

Tags: qgis, qfield, altitude

I'm trying to collect the altitude from the GPS of my phone in the a field a create. Here's the situation:

- A have a point geometry file saved in a gpk
- A field "Altitude", type double
- And in the formular, I tried to set up the default value as z($geometry) or z(@position_coordinate)  and neither will save the value when I collect a point from QField.

Comment: your point geometry file needs the z dimension when it is created. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340889/can-qfield-record-gps-z-value